# PHP Generating Signature with big Endian

Tags: php, hash

I am trying to generate a signature as suggested here: https://www.reed.co.uk/developers/SignatureTest

This is what they say at the bottom of their page. But I don't understand this!

```
If you use a language like C\C++ and Perl, your processor architecture could generated different arrangement of bits for your API Key.
Check at the section below if your API key bytes are arranged in the same way that we use to validate your signature.
API Token (Hexadecimal Notation)
[0x5A] [0x74] [0xD7] [0xDA] [0x32] [0x16] [0x62] [0x47] [0xA8] [0x55] [0x64] [0xC6] [0xA7] [0xC4] [0x0B] [0x56]
How can I fix it ?
If the arrange of bits is not the same, this might be a indication that it is in a little endian format.
You will need to swap the bytes from one little endian to big endian to get achieve the same signature. You can find more about Byte Swapping Libraries searching on Google or Bing .
```

This is what I am doing:

```
function createSignature($queryUrl, $timestamp, $apiKey, $http = "GET", $agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"){
    $signature = $http . $agent . $queryUrl . "www.reed.co.uk" . $timestamp;
    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", $signature, $apiKey, true));
    return $signature;
}


$clientId = 1;
$timestamp = "2016-05-13T09:22:50Z";

$apiKey = "bacd2d2d-8b69-43c8-94c5-4a24c0269b79";

$queryUrl = "https://www.reed.co.uk/recruiter/api/1.0/cvsearch";

$reedQuery = \Httpful\Request::get($queryUrl)
    ->addHeaders(array(
        "X-ApiSignature" => createSignature($queryUrl, $timestamp, $apiKey),
        "X-ApiClientId" => $clientId,
        "X-TimeStamp" => $timestamp
    ))
    ->expectsJson()
    ->send();
```

Now for some reasons it returns this on my server: WRTjqQKfyEQyLJEzWWuT3SWgGPk= While the expected result is: JUgvCh5oeFYe1HDmfiMObOu1+nQ=

I tried everything, even swapping from little endian to big endian. Nothing.

What is wrong??? :(

Comment: Strangely enough https://www.reed.co.uk/developers/SignatureTest doesn't work at all for me with the credentials you've supplied. It's throwing a server exception.

Comment: @apokryfos very well...

Comment: I'm only mentioning this because I was trying to confirm that  `JUgvCh5oeFYe1HDmfiMObOu1+nQ=` is indeed the expected result which the page mentions.